# Rent dissipation meaning?

Tags: microeconomics, utility

What is Rent dissipation? Please explain with an example.
I tried to search it on the internet about it. And I couldn't find anything in simple language. It was the esoteric language and was unclear. I wish there might have been a simple paragraph out there that could explain its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this article useful [Licensing and Rent Dissipation](https://www.romeconomics.com/licensing-rent-dissipation/).

In simple terms you might think of it as the devaluation of an 'asset' of some sort.

Comment: Thanks Pelinore. That was helpful.